# How can I launch a UWP app in TRUE fullscreen mode?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

The goal is to switch the display into TRUE fullscreen mode, rather than the F11-key fullscreen implementation. It would be the equivalent of launch your typical Steam fullscreen game, if that makes things any clearer, and so I would have full control of changing the display resolution, etc.

I noticed that many UWP-based "fullscreen" games don't really go into true fullscreen mode: hovering the mouse at the bottom of the screen reveals the taskbar, etc. But I did notice that some other games do go into true fullscreen mode: Minecraft Dungeons, for example, and so it is very much possible.

Do I need a game engine or something to accomplish this? My app isn't a game so I hope not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the [official sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FullScreenMode/cs). Use the [ApplicationView.TryEnterFullScreenMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryenterfullscreenmode?view=winrt-19041) method could switch the app in full-screen mode at runtime. Use the [ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.preferredlaunchwindowingmode?view=winrt-19041) property with a value  `ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen` could let the app launch in full-screen mode. If you don’t want the taskbar to show when hovering the mouse at the bottom of the screen, you could use [ApplicationView.FullScreenSystemOverlayMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.fullscreensystemoverlaymode?view=winrt-19041) property with a value `FullScreenSystemOverlayMode.Minimal` to do it.

You could try to add the following code in `OnLaunched` method to launch a UWP app in full-screen mode:
App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    ……

    ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
    var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
    view.FullScreenSystemOverlayMode = FullScreenSystemOverlayMode.Minimal;

}
```